# Type mismatch: inferred type is but was expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger-2, android-databinding

I'm new to Kotlin and here is my problem:

I use dataBinding in my app and When I want to set my variable from layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
            name="noteViewModel"
            type="moeindeveloper.kotlinroomaac.ViewModel.NoteViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".View.MainActivity">
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="@{noteViewModel.isLoading.get() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/repository_rv"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/repository_rv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/repository_rv" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/repository_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="@{noteViewModel.isLoading.get() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row_item" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My main activity:

```
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
```

on create:

```
val viewModel:NoteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory)
        .get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

    binding.noteViewModel = viewModel
    binding.executePendingBindings()
```

so up to this point, my code is correct but, when I hit run,
I face these errors:

```
Cannot access class 'ViewModel.NoteViewModel'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Type mismatch: inferred type is moeindeveloper.kotlinroomaac.ViewModel.NoteViewModel but ViewModel.NoteViewModel? was expected
```

I use android studio 3.2.1
kotlin version: 1.2.71

any thoughts on this?

Comment: Compiler was expecting `NoteViewModel?` but it's getting `NoteViewModel` (the difference is the `?` that indicates it may be null)

Comment: i think this code ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory)
        .get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

is returning a Nullable type

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA nope! I think it's because of the new android studio. I had the same project before the update and it worked! but after the update I face this issue

Comment: Maybe it's a problem similar to the one I was facing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550348/type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-homeactivity-but-callbackkotlin-collections-arr  
I had to change the server response so to make it work at that time.

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA Yeah I have this issue too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it by adding the following line to my gradle.properties:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=false
```

Comment: getting this response : "The option setting 'android.databinding.enableV2=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'"

Comment: It's just a warning, you can ignore it!

Comment: I add the line definition, the Build console appears the error as below:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.application']
   > The option 'android.databinding.enableV2' is deprecated.
     The current default is 'true'.
     It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
     Databinding v1 is removed.

Comment: This is deprecated

Comment: Removed in current gradle version. Does not work!

Answer (score 8):

Even though this is getting old, I found out that the problem came from the fact that my packages started with an uppercase.

You should check yours.

I find it very weird and frustrating that package naming influences the compiler as much.

gl
Lawnio

edit: to avoid misunderstanding, I had the exact same two errors you were having.

Comment: yes! I found out this too! after changing package names, I never faced that problem! weird!

Comment: Made my Day! <3

Comment: Thanks, helped! Android never ceases to amaze me. But what is strictly technical reason of that behavior?
BTW, I had to keep class name starting with capital letter, otherwise I received "can't guess" error xD

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Activity If You Use the **Binding** keyword Then This is Conflict